# dynamic LinkButton OnClick event not working on ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asplinkbutton

I want to create dynamic LinkButton for image, `<img>` tag is not working dynamically so I am using LinkButton with image.
I don't want to provide ID to LinkButton because I want to generate more LinkButton dynamically.
I am using following code in Default.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <script runat="server">   
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Response.Write(@"<asp:LinkButton runat=""server"" OnClick=""btn_click""><img src=""close-icon (1).png"" /></asp:LinkButton>");
            }

            public void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Response.Write("HELLO");
            }   
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried to write  tag code in Default.aspx.cs file but not work.
It's showing me following error.

> Error 1   'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for
>   'img_Click' and no extension method 'img_Click' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'ASP.default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Why are you using Response.Write? Never seen someone do it like that. Create a control instance and add it to the page.

Comment: I am using Response.Write because I am creating site, in this site data received from Database and it's show on Site with button with every rows which retrieve from Database Table, If you have any other Idea for this then tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer,answer is below

Default.aspx.cs Page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class dynamicimage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = @"<asp:ImageButton ID=""dynoimage"" ImageUrl=""~/images/about01.jpg"" runat=""server"" oncommand=""clickme"" commandname=""btn"" />";
        Control c = ParseControl(str);
        form1.Controls.Add(c);
        ((ImageButton)Page.FindControl("dynoimage")).Command += new CommandEventHandler(clickme);
    }

    protected void clickme(object sender,CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Image clicked");
        Label1.Text = "Image clicked";
    }
}
```

and here is the Default.aspx Page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="dynamicimage.aspx.cs" Inherits="dynamicimage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="before click"></asp:Label>
    </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got the approach wrong, your first Response.Write("...") not the Response.Write("

Read this aritcle to use controls in ASP.NET dynamically.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Mr. Guru Kara, I think you not read full question, I want to create dynamic LinkButton for image without ID so I am using this way and it's working but event not work, without click event it's working properly,It's working for all tag with this method.
Give me any way so event can work by this way.

Comment: Events wont work unless you re-add the control in post backs to the control hierarchy in Pre_init event. Read this article fully then go for implementation cause dynamic controls in ASP.NET is not as easy as it seems, LINK==weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx

Comment: Mr. Guru Kara, you link is not working, when I open it, it's show me page not found.

Comment: Just google "truly understanding dynamic controls asp.net" you should get a asp.net webblog called infinite loop